# strange result when summing up count("reviews".id) + count("comments".id) as my_count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In a query below I count how many reviews and comments publication have. I summing up reviews and comments like that: **.select('"publications".*, count("reviews".id) + count("comments".id) as my_count')**.

Assuming publication have 3 reviews and 3 comments in sum would be 6, however my_count always shows bigger number. What is happening behind the curtain and how to make it count normally?

```
Publication.joins(:reviews, :comments)
                                  .select('"publications".*, count("reviews".id) + count("comments".id) as my_count')
                                  .group('"publications".id')
                                  .order("my_count DESC")
```

Answer (score 1):

The generated SQL probably looks like this:

```
SELECT publications.id, COUNT(reviews.id) + COUNT(comments.id) AS my_count
FROM publications p
INNER JOIN reviews r ON p.id = r.publication_id
INNER JOIN comments c ON p.id = c.publication_id
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY my_count DESC
```

Let's get rid of grouping for a moment and see what's going on on the following input:

```
publications: [{ id: 1 }],
reviews: [{ publication_id: 1, id: 1 }, { publication_id: 1, id: 2 },{ publication_id: 1, id: 3 }]
comments: [{ publication_id: 1, id: 10 }, { publication_id: 1, id: 20 }]
```

So there are are 3 reviews and 2 comments. However, this query will return 6 rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM publications p
INNER JOIN reviews r ON p.id = review.publication_id
INNER JOIN comments c ON p.id = comment.publication_id

publication.id | review.id | comment.id
1              | 1         | 10
1              | 2         | 10
1              | 3         | 10
1              | 1         | 20
1              | 2         | 20
1              | 3         | 20
```

And, when you group it, it will return 6+6 = 12 as a total count.
One possible workaround is to do `COUNT(DISTINCT reviews.id) + COUNT(DISTINCT comments.id)`. Probably, this is not the best solution in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

As DNNX points out, this occurs because you have fallen into what is called a "Chasm trap" -- the row count is inflated because of the multiple one-to-many joins.

You could try this as a shortterm alternative:

```
Publication.select('"publications".*,
                     coalesce((select count(*) from reviews r where r.publication_id = pubications.id),0)
                     + coalesce((select count(*) from comments c where c.publication_id = pubications.id),0) as my_count')
            .order("my_count DESC")
```

However I'd suggest you place counter caches on Publication for reviews and comments.